# What is '<Invoke>d__40'?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Using Powershell, System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.Invoke() returns object of type `'<Invoke>d__40'` rather than specified OutputType.

To reproduce:

1. Copy [SendGreeting example cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-write-a-simple-cmdlet?view=powershell-5.1#example) to .\ExampleCmdlet.cs
2. `powershell -NoProfile`
3. `Add-Type -Path .\ExampleCmdlet.cs`
4. `$command = [SendGreeting.SendGreetingCommand]::new()`
5. `$command.Name = 'Person'`
6. `$invoke = $command.Invoke()`
7. `$invoke.GetType()`

**Expected**: `[string]`
**Actual**: `[<Invoke>d__40]`

$PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1237
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1237
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

`Get-Member -InputObject $invoke` reveals this to implement [IEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=netframework-4.8) and some playing with `.MoveNext()` and `.Current` will sometimes output the expected `"Hello Person!"` result.

What is this `<Invoke>d__40` type?
Why is `$command.Invoke()` not returning the expected string output directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [Guru Stron's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72265158/45375), which explains that the name of the specific type returned is just an implementation detail; what matters is that the type implements the [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface:

The fact that the type *also* implements the [`System.Collections.IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) interface, as you've discovered, makes it a *lazy* (on-demand) enumerable: that is, the object returned doesn't itself *contain* data, it *retrieves / generates data when enumerated*.

If you *output* `$invoke`, PowerShell *implicitly* enumerates the enumerable, and you should see the expected outcome:

```sh
PS> $invoke  # enumeration happens here.
Hello Person!
```

Note that an attempt to access `$invoke` *again* produces *no* output, because the enumeration has completed (and even trying to reset it with `.Reset()` doesn't work, because the type implementing the interface doesn't support it).

- Note: It is not unusual for lazy enumerables to *support* repeat enumeration, despite also not implementing the `.Reset()` method; e.g., in the following examples `$enumerator` can be enumerated repeatedly, and yields the same results every time: `$enumerator = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(1,10)` and `$enumerator = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD/test.txt")`

By contrast, assigning `$invoke` to a *variable* does *not* cause enumeration: `$result = $invoke` merely creates another reference to the enumerator itself.

In order to capture the actual object(s) to be enumerated, you must *force enumeration* via `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) or `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--); e.g.:

```sh
# Note: This assumes you haven't output $invoke by itself before.
$result = $($invoke) # force enumeration and store the enumerated object(s)
```

---

**Taking a step back:**

*Lazy* enumerables aren't that common in normal PowerShell code, and if you use them in an enumeration context - notably in the pipeline or in a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) - they'll work as expected.

When you assign a lazy enumerable to a variable, you need to be aware that you're storing just the enumerator, not the data it will enumerate.

If you use your sample cmdlet as it is meant to be used - by invoking it as *command* `Send-Greeting` with a `-Name` *argument* - the lazy enumerable is eliminated from the picture, because cmdlets output actual data:

```sh
# Directly outputs string 'Hello Person!'
Send-Greeting -Name Person
```

To make your sample cmdlet callable this way, you need to not only load the implementing type's assembly into your session with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type), you must additionally *import* it *as a PowerShell module*, with [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module):

```sh
# Compile and load the assembly, and also import it as a PowerShell module,
# so the cmdlet that is implemented surfaces as such.
(Add-type -PassThru -LiteralPath .\ExampleCmdlet.cs).Assembly | Import-Module

# Now you can call your Send-Greeting cmdlet.
Send-Greeting -Name Person
```

Answer (score 5):

`<Invoke>d__40` is name of compiler generated class:

`Cmdlet.Invoke`/`Cmdlet.Invoke<T>` returns `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` and [is implemented](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/cmdlet.cs#L1615) using [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) which results in compiler generating as special named class (compiler can use `<` and `>` symbols in identifiers while developers can't) which implements `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` (check out for example [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgMIHsA2mCmBjAFwEt0A7AZwG4BYAKDqgGYEAmOVOAbzrl4WaTMAkqQBu6ANY4AFAEouPPkqSIEAdjiIatJQF86uoA=) decompilation).