# Get current method name in .NET Core 6

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

I am looking to get the current executing method in .NET Core 6

When using

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName
```

the output is `<MethodName>d__6`

How to get only `MethodName` ?

What is `d__6` ?

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239621/2501279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264331/what-is-invoked-40)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```